# How to efficiently track my geolocation during traveling using iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I'm going to travel through Thailand and I want to keep track of my location to geotag photos afterwards taken with a digital camera (iPhone's camera is not good enough). There are two things that are important here:

- I don't want to update manually
- I want the battery to last as long as possible, since the times I will be able to charge will be scarce

I've thought about creating a web page that periodically sends my geolocation to a script that stores it in a database, but I don't know if GPS data is available in Mobile Safari. Second, I want the data I send to be as small as possible, and the frequency this is done s few as possible, because of the pricing of mobile data usage abroad.

Any suggestions what would be a good solution here?

Comment: Not quite an answer, but you should store compare your coordinate, with the last coordinate you took. If it's further then a certain distance, record it, else ignore. That way you only update when you have moved enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if GPS data would be available in Mobile Safari. But, you could obviously create an app that does this.

One design thing that could be different however is that you can save locally to files (or a database) the coordinates instead of uploading each time. That way you won't actually be sending any data and avoid the data upload charge.

And as for battery life, you can select a time interval at which you read your coordinates instead of constantly updating. Also not using GPS for the location might be more efficient battery-wise (I am just guessing here though).

Comment: I came to the same conclusion when I thought about it more. I think this is the best (and cheapest) way. Do you know if an app continues to function if you put the phone in sleep mode (by pressing the top button)? 

In any case, thanks for your input!